# Find max value in a column knowing only a part of the value

Tags: excel, vba, max, criteria

I'm stuck with finding the max value in a column based on a criteria that I know only a part of it.

Let me explain better, here is my table

[image]

What I would like to do is:

1) Find the max number in Column A based on my 1st criteria that is "1". 
2) If I have the criteria "1" I would like to find the max number that begins with "1", so in our example the max number would be "10010".

Some tips of how I would obtain this? If you prefer VBA is a valid option also.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option, something like the following:

```
=MAX(IF(LEFT(A2:A8,1)="1",A2:A8))
```

[image]

Array formula, so depending on your version of Excel you may need to confirm with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Wow! Why it did not consider "20000" also? It's greater than "10010"

Comment: But `Left(20000,1)` doesn't equal 1. The first part of the formula effectively replaces 20000 with 0, well actually FALSE. You can use *Formulas* > *Evaluate Formula* to see what the formula is doing.

Comment: Hey @BigBen I'm strugling to write this formula in VBA excel where the number `="1"` is a variable. Could you help me out?

Comment: Sure. Maybe ask as a new question and ping me here?

Comment: here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59949930/write-properly-a-formula-in-vba-excel