# Write a formula in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm struggling to write a formula in Excel VBA.

This is my code:

```
Dim Formula as Range
Dim Number as Integer

Number = 1

Formula.formula = "=MAX(IF(LEFT(B7:B250,1)= & Number &, B7:B250))"
```

It gives a syntax error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I insert variable into formula in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503316/how-can-i-insert-variable-into-formula-in-vba)

Comment: You are missing some quotes: `"=MAX(IF(LEFT(B7:B250,1)=" & Number & ",B7:B250))"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some quotes:

```
"=MAX(IF(LEFT(B7:B250,1)=" & Number & ",B7:B250))"
```

Also, this is an array formula so use `.FormulaArray` instead of `.Formula`.

Comment: Seems like I still get error: run-time: 91. Im looking for it

Comment: You need to `Set` your range. (Also, use a different variable name than `Formula`).

Comment: Yess it worked, but `debug.print Formula` does not work??? I would like to know what is inside

Comment: What are you trying to `Debug.Print`? Should be `Debug.Print "=MAX(IF(LEFT(B7:B250,1)=" & Number & ",B7:B250))"`?

Comment: Ah there is not a result inside Formula? I mean after we did `.FormulaArray` is there not a result inside?

Comment: Oh you can `Debug.Print` the `Formula` or `FormulaArray` too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60095600/write-properly-a-formula-in-excel-vba Can you look at this question?