# Write properly a formula in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I already asked a question like this before, but seems that the answer given is not working in this case

this is my code:

```
Worksheets("Sheet").Range(myRange).formula = "=CONCATENATE(CODICI!" & stringCodiceCella & ";" & stringDesignazioneCella & ")"
```

Note that stringCodiceCella is a String, and stringDesignazioneCella is also a String.

Following this link [A working example of formula in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59949930/write-properly-a-formula-in-vba-excel)

I can't see the error.

Comment: Use a comma `,` instead of a semicolon `;`.

Comment: Wow! How? Who are you?

Comment: Use the **,** as the separator rather than the **;**

Comment: Should "CODICI!" be a string? If yes, you should add double quotes around it like "" CODICI!""

Comment: @Boketto not it's the name of the Sheet, sorry I didn't write it properly, btw the solution provided by THE BIG BEN is working like a charm. As always he is so fast :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "," in place of ";" as suggested by @BigBen

`Worksheets("Sheet").Range(myRange).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(CODICI!" & stringCodiceCella & "," & stringDesignazioneCella & ")"`

Or use `FormulaLocal`

`Worksheets("Sheet").Range(myRange).FormulaLocal = "=CONCATENATE(CODICI!" & stringCodiceCella & ";" & stringDesignazioneCella & ")"`

**Edit:**
See below code.

`Worksheets("Sheet").Range(myRange).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(CODICI!" & stringCodiceCella & ",""-""," & stringDesignazioneCella & ")"`

`Worksheets("Sheet").Range(myRange).FormulaLocal = "=CONCATENATE(CODICI!" & stringCodiceCella & ";""-"";" & stringDesignazioneCella & ")"`

Comment: I'm going to accept the answer but I just want to ask you. If I would like to put a simple " - " in the middle of the two strings so I can have a better view of it, where do i put it?

Comment: @ChangeWorld If you have Office365 or Office2019, then you can swap from `CONCATENATE` to `TEXTJOIN`, which supports delimiters suck as "-"

Comment: @ChangeWorld See edit section formula which shall help.

Comment: @Chronocidal unfortunately I have office 2016 for now.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij It's not working, it gives me incorrect type. Why did didn't you use comma instead of semicolon?

Comment: @ChangeWorld refer both formulas. Both should work!